# "ImportError: No module named site" with Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter

Hi Stack Overflow community, I've been encountering the titular error when trying to run the command 'jupyter notebook'

I'm running a fresh install of Scientific Linux 7. When opening a new terminal I can run the Jupyter notebook in my browser with no problem. I installed a package that includes its own Python distribution, and requires me to run a setup script before using. After running the setup script (which does various things to my environment variables) Jupyter no longer works (gives me the "No module named site" error).

Googling told me to try unsetting both PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, but that didn't work. Could someone explain to me how the environment variables change how Python looks for packages? Please let me know if I can clarify something to make answering my query easier.

Thanks!

Edit: the setup script is not very illuminating as far as I can tell. For reference the package I'm looking to use is the Fermi Science Tools (http://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/ssc/data/analysis/software/). Here's the code for the setup script (some of the indentation may be off a bit because I'm new to this, but rest assured the script runs without a hitch)

```
#  Filename: fermi-init.sh
# Description: Bourne-shell flavor initialization for all FERMI software.
#              Runs fermi-setup to generate a sh script tailored
#              specifically to this user and FERMI software
#              installation, then source that.
# Author/Date: James Peachey, HEASARC/GSFC/NASA, May 3, 1999
# Modified for HEADAS December 2001
# Adapted for FERMI September 2008
#
#if [ "x$HEADAS" = x ]; then
#  echo "fermi-init.sh: WARNING -- set HEADAS and source headas-init.sh before sourcing fermi-init.sh!"         
#  echo "Do you wish to proceed with sourcing?"
#   select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    #       case $yn in
        #           Yes ) 
            #               if [ "x$FERMI_DIR" = x ]; then 
                #                   echo "fermi-init.sh: ERROR -- set FERMI_DIR before sourcing fermi-init.sh"
            #               elif [ -x "$FERMI_DIR/BUILD_DIR/fermi-setup" ]; then
                #                   export FERMI_INST_DIR=${FERMI_DIR}
                #                   fermi_init=`$FERMI_INST_DIR/BUILD_DIR/fermi-setup sh`
                #                   if [ $? -eq 0 -a "x$fermi_init" != x ]; then
                #                   if [ -f "$fermi_init" ]; then
                    #                       . $fermi_init
                #                   fi
                #                   rm -f $fermi_init
                #                   fi
                #                   unset fermi_init
            #               else
                #                   echo "fermi-init.sh: ERROR -- cannot execute $FERMI_DIR/BUILD_DIR/fermi-setup"
            #               fi
            #               break;;
        #           No )
            #               break;;
    #       esac
#done
#else
  if [ "x$FERMI_DIR" = x ]; then 
 echo "fermi-init.sh: ERROR -- set FERMI_DIR before sourcing fermi-init.sh"
  elif [ -x "$FERMI_DIR/BUILD_DIR/fermi-setup" ]; then
  export FERMI_INST_DIR=${FERMI_DIR}
  fermi_init=`$FERMI_INST_DIR/BUILD_DIR/fermi-setup sh`
  if [ $? -eq 0 -a "x$fermi_init" != x ]; then
  if [ -f "$fermi_init" ]; then
      . $fermi_init
  fi
  rm -f $fermi_init
  fi
  unset fermi_init
  else
  echo "fermi-init.sh: ERROR -- cannot execute  $FERMI_DIR/BUILD_DIR/fermi-setup"
fi
#fi
```

Comment: It's hard to know what's the problem without seeing your setup script

Comment: `site` is normally a *built-in* module; it comes with the Python binary. Not being able to import `site` is... unsettling, to say the least.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Jupyter kernal from your browser after running the setup script?

Comment: Generally messing with environment variables that impact Python imports is a bad idea. The only time it makes sense to is when using a virtualenv, and even then activating a virtualenv manipulates just a few variables like `PATH` in *just* the right way. Reason being that the `python` executable had a default list of paths it searches for modules, and this is generally the correct path for that Python installation. To start debugging this I suggest posting the output of `env` (minus any sensitive data) and the output of `which python`, `which jupyter`, `head $(which jupyter)` and so on.

Comment: Docker is a good solution too, but it's an end run around actually understanding how your system works.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I work at [Datmo](https://datmo.com), where we’re building a new tool to improve quantitative workflows.**

I would highly suggest using Docker in this case. You can setup your environment using a container instead. For example, in your case you might be running on Scientific Linux 7, so you can directly install the Fermi Science Tools, but instead you could just use a standard linux installation (CentOS, Debian, or Ubuntu) and install Docker from [this link](https://store.docker.com/search?type=edition&offering=community).

Once you have that installed you can pull the image as is written on [this page](https://hub.docker.com/r/sfegan/fermitools_ubuntu/) using the command:

```
docker pull sfegan/fermitools_ubuntu
```

You can then run any code you want by running `docker run` ([docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/))

If you're working on a particularly difficult quantitative workflow (e.g. working with large scientific data sets etc), there are free tools like [Datmo](https://datmo.com) which use Docker to help you set this up.